# Implementation of Unscented Kalman Filter

Tags: python, kalman-filter

I have this code:

```
def fx(x, dt):
    # state transition functioin - predict next state based
    # on constant velocity model x = vt + x_0
    F = np.array([[1, 0, dt, 0],
                  [0, 1, 0, dt]])
    return np.dot(F,x)

def hx(x):
    # Extract the relative NE_X and NE_Y coordinates from the state vector x
    x, y = x[0], x[1]
    
    # Calculate distance
    distance = math.sqrt((x)**2 + (y)**2)

    # Calculate bearing in radians
    bearing = math.atan2(y, x)

    return np.array([[bearing], [distance]])

### UKF ###
### Preparation of the data ###
first_bearing = bearings[0]
first_distance = distances[0]

# Calculate the position of the object related to the boat frame
relative_ne_x = first_distance * math.cos(first_bearing)
relative_ne_y = first_distance * math.sin(first_bearing)

### Define the initial values and the functions ###

# Store the values in variable x if needed
x = np.array([relative_ne_x, relative_ne_y]) # Initial state
P = np.diag([1, 1])  # initial uncertainty

points = MerweScaledSigmaPoints(n=2, alpha=1e-3, beta=2, kappa=0)
ukf = UKF(dim_x=4, dim_z=2, dt=1.5, fx=fx, hx=hx, points=points)

ukf.x = x  # initial state
ukf.P = P  # initial uncertainty
z_std1 = np.radians(5)  # degrees
z_std2 = 20  # meters
ukf.R = np.diag([z_std1**2, z_std2**2])  # measurement noise covariance matrix
ukf.Q = Q_discrete_white_noise(dim=2, var=0.01**2, dt=1.5, block_size=2)  # process noise covariance matrix

# Get a subset of bearings and distances starting from the start_index
subset_bearings = bearings[1:]
subset_distances = distances[1:]

zs = [[bearing, distance] for [bearing, distance] in zip(subset_bearings, subset_distances)] # measurements
print(zs)
for z in zs:
    ukf.predict()
    ukf.update(z)
    print(ukf.x, 'log-likelihood', ukf.log_likelihood)
```

However, I get this error, even if everythins seems correct:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/LABSF/Main.py", line 354, in <module>
    ukf.predict()
  File "Desktop/LABSF/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/filterpy/kalman/UKF.py", line 388, in predict
    self.compute_process_sigmas(dt, fx, **fx_args)
  File "Desktop/LABSF/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/filterpy/kalman/UKF.py", line 503, in compute_process_sigmas
    self.sigmas_f[i] = fx(s, dt, **fx_args)
TypeError: fx() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I tried to modify all the code increasing the number of initial states with the x and y velocities, but the problem remains, instead of having 1 and passing 2 I will have 2 and passing 4.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, don't have enough reputation to comment)

Based off of what is in your code, it seems your state vector has 2 states: the North/East position of a boat. Your dynamics function `fx` where you multiply a matrix `F` by your state takes in a size 4 state and outputs a size 2 vector. I would suggest taking another look at the dynamics function.

It might make sense to have three states: North position, East position, and bearing? (Bearing measured as angle off of East, positive in North direction) Then your dynamics could look like

```
    e_k+1 = e_k + velocity * cos(bearing_k) * dt
    n_k+1 = n_k + velocity * sin(bearing_k) * dt
    bearing_k+1 = bearing_k
```

If you have more information about what the dynamics are supposed to be, then I can give more suggestions on how to write the dynamics function.